# How to exclude items from search using NOT LIKE and % in Presto SQL?

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following query that returned an error: **mismatched input 'LIKE'. Expecting: expression**

```
select * from sales
where item_name NOT LIKE '%Tortoise%'
```

The image below illustrates what I want to get from my source data. I want records that do not contain the keyword "Tortoise".

[image]

Appreciate any advice on how to correct this syntax, thank you.

Comment: Your query should work.  It is possible Presto doesn't understand `NOT LIKE` and prefers `NOT item_name LIKE '%Tortoise%' `.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hi, I corrected it but now the issue is with the data type. My item_name column is in varbinary and when I cast it to varchar to do a comparison with NOT LIKE expression, the query returned an error " Cannot cast varbinary to varchar". Do you know what I should do to resolve this?

Comment: @GordonLinoff if i follow `NOT item_name LIKE '%Tortoise%'` - I will get this `error line 25:9: Left side of LIKE expression must evaluate to a varchar (actual: varbinary)`

Comment: `NOT LIKE` is certainly supported in Presto. If `item_name` is `varbinary`, you need to convert this first to `varchar`, perhaps using [`from_utf8()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#from_utf8) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may get you the expected result.

```
select * 
from sales
where item_name NOT IN (
   select * 
   from sales
   where item_name LIKE '%Tortoise%'
)
```

Comment: @adelle . . . It makes no sense that this would work but your query would not.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work, 'NOT LIKE' is supported in presto and for the issue from the comments related to Varchar you can cast it to Varchar. So the final query becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE CAST(item_name AS varchar) NOT LIKE '%Tortoise%' ;
```